# How to redirect traffic between VPN

Tags: redirect, traffic

I have many interfaces and subnets (local and vpn) on ubuntu router
but i need to remap traffic  from openVPN to IPSEC tunnel trough defined subnet

destination ip is 1.2.3.4
ipsec tunnel accept traffic to 1.2.3.4 only from source network 3.4.5.40/29 
eth1:2 ip is 3.4.5.41

clients subnet is 192.168.68.0/24(tun0)

How to connect to 1.2.3.4 by them

I did tried many variants with SNAT without success
I imagine that I must redirect traffic  tun0 -> eth1:2 -> 1.2.3.4 and back

Best Regards

Comment: I think you also might need a FORWARD rule between the interfaces like

`-A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth1:2 -j ACCEPT`

and back

`-A FORWARD -i eth1:2 -o  tun0 -j ACCEPT`

Comment: It's work! 10x derHugo!

Comment: Glad to hear that ;) happy networking so!